# Integrate Monaco editor in Laravel to use it

Tags: laravel, vue.js, monaco-editor

Somebody already successfully integrated Monaco editor in Laravel 6.x ?
I tried to use `https://github.com/FE-Mars/monaco-editor-vue` but so far I found 12 Bugs which makes it hard to use:

- Doesn't show Contextmenu
- Doubleclick a Word doesn't highlight similar Words
- Deselection is not possible
- Indentation changes after a while
- `Ctrl+#` Commenting a Line doesn't work
- `Ctrl+Shift+Left` Doesn't work properly.
- `Ctrl+Del` doesn't work
- Collapsing / Expanding doesn't work
- Auto Completion doesn't work
- `Ctrl + Backspace` doesn't work
- Search doesn't work
- Syntax Highlighting not working for `javascript` ( only for `python` )

I added all the possible Features from the `monaco-editor-webpack-plugin` Plugin but no one works.

[image]

If somebody can help that would be nice.

Comment: any error in the console?

Comment: None. All good. By uninstalling `monaco-editor-vue` and using Monaco Editor directly it works and all Features working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Found a Solution by using Monaco Editor directly and not use `monaco-editor-vue` fixed all Issues.